# Implicit parameter cast

Tags: c

I have a C code that works in the following way: the header contains a declaration for the function, say:

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
    int thing;
    void* reserved;
} MyStruct;

void foo(MyStruct* bar);
```

And then, in my .c code, I have this:

```
typedef struct EXTENDED
{
    float more_stuff;
} EXTENDED;

struct MyStructEx
{
    int thing;
    EXTENDED* ex;
} MyStructEx;

void foo(MyStructEx* bar)
{
    ...
}
```

This compiles fine under MSVC (with warnings telling me that the header and implementation parameters don't match) but Code::Blocks (GCC) throws an error on it. Is there a way to silence this error or at least make it a warning, or is my only option to put the extra definitions in the header as well?

I'm doing this because I'm coding a modular library in C, so sometimes the individual components require "scratch space" to work (which is the void* reserved in the header), and to avoid having a bunch of casts everywhere I'm trying to implicitly cast the general-purpose MyStruct structure to a more specialized one.

So my question is, which option should I use to change this sort of error into a warning, and/or is there a better way to achieve this? (I am required to use standard C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the function prototype and cast the pointer in the function definition

```
typedef struct EXTENDED
{
    float more_stuff;
} EXTENDED;

struct MyStructEx
{
    int thing;
    EXTENDED* ex;
} MyStructEx;

void foo(MyStruct* bar)
{
    MyStructEx *mse = (MyStructEx*)bar;
    ...
}
```

It will shut the compiler.

Comment: That requires having an additional pointer in the implementation though, it would be optimized away but it isn't very elegant to read. Valid solution if all else fails though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit conversion between `MyStruct*` and `MyStructEx*`.

(A terminology quibble: there's no such thing as an "implicit cast". A cast is an explicit conversion, using the cast operator, which consists of a parenthesized type name.)

There's also no guarantee that `void*` and `EXTENDED*` have the same size and representation; it would be perfectly legal, for example, for `void*` to be 8 bytes and `EXTENDED*` to be 4 bytes.

Any technique that assumes `MyStruct` and `MyStructEx` have the same layout is going to cause your program's behavior to be undefined.

It seems like the `foo` function that takes a `MyStruct*` and the `foo` function that takes a `MyStructEx*` need to be two different functions, with two different names. One of them can be a wrapper for the other.

Either that, or you could drop the `MyStructEx` type and use `MyStruct` for everything, with `foo()` doing any necessary conversions.

Comment: "There's also no guarantee that void* and EXTENDED* have the same size and representation" How so? They are both pointers, aren't pointers always the same size in a given process? I'm confused.
"Either that, or you could drop the MyStructEx type and use MyStruct for everything, with foo() doing any necessary conversions." Yes that is a last option.

Comment: @Thomas C is a programming language that has abstractions, including types. It is not an assembler language where a variable declaration inevitable implies pushing the stackpointer and where a pointer is just a number.

Comment: @Thomas: There's no guarantee about anything for pointers, except that all pointers can be converted to `void *` and back.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Actually there's a guarantee that all struct pointers have the same representation, as do all union pointers (this is useful for pointers to incomplete types). Also, `void*` has the same representation as `char*`, `unsigned char*`, and `signed char*`. There's also a guarantee that round-trip function pointer conversion yields the original value. (None of these guarantees are directly helpful here.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks - the `void*` and `char*` correspondence is particularly useful to know. Do you have the reference for that?

Comment: @KerrekSB: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (C11 draft) 6.2.5p28. Paragraph 27 in [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (C99 draft).